# Does sklearn.metrics.log_loss support multilabel setting?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Does [sklearn.metrics.log_loss](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.log_loss.html) support multilabel setting?

By multilabel setting I mean input can be like:

```
y_pred_arr = np.array([[0.4,0.9,0.3], [1.0,0.4,0.1]], np.float32)
y_true_arr = np.array([[1,0,0], [1,0,1]], np.float32)
```

i.e. 2 samples, 3 labels.